# document.documentElement doesn't maintain style property assigned with 'html' selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have assigned some css styles to the select 'html' like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html { background-color:blue; }
</style>
```

Through javascript, I would like to access the style attribute like this (an example):

```
alert( document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor);
```

In Chrome, the attribute is null, in FF it is an empty string. It seems I can access the html element via a CSS selector but not through javascript via the document.documentElement ... hmmm, any suggestions on how I can access the styles (via javascript) set by the css html selector?

Thanks in advance, Rein

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
window
    .getComputedStyle( document.documentElement )
    .getPropertyValue( 'background-color' )
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5jtqC/

The `style` property only reads inline styles, not the styles defined by a style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

`element.style` only deals with inline styles via the `style` attribute.

To get the current style of the element, use:

```
(element.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(element)).backgroundColor;
```